Java Spring boot Zipkin Micrometer
I am trying to enable method execution time tracking so I can see the execution times on Zipkin. I am using a micrometer for that. I have set up my application in a docker container and I have also Zipkin in a docker container. I know that there is a connection between my application container and the Zipkin container because I can see it receives HTTP requests and so on. This is how I have modified the method that I want to track in the service layer:
  @Transactional
    public Page<W> getAll(
            UUID distributionCenterId,
            Pageable pageable,
            Language language
    ) {
        String methodName = "getAll";
        log.debug("{} - Entry. Get all entities", methodName);

        Span span = tracer.nextSpan().name(methodName).start();
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        try {
            pageable = validatePageable(pageable, methodName);

            Page<W> response;

            // Try to get the entities from the cache if cacheService is available
            if (cacheService != null) {
                Optional<List<LR>> cachedResponse = cacheService.getAll(distributionCenterId, language.toString());
                if (cachedResponse.isPresent()) {
                    log.debug("{} - Cache hit for all entities with distributionCenterId: '{}'", methodName, distributionCenterId);
                    response = new PageImpl<>(
                            cachedResponse.get().stream().map(this::createWrapper).collect(Collectors.toList()),
                            pageable,
                            cachedResponse.get().size()
                    );
                    log.info("{} - Exit. Found all entities from cache: '{}'", methodName, response);

                    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
                    long duration = endTime - startTime;
                    span.tag("duration", String.valueOf(duration));

                    return response;
                }
                log.debug("{} - Cache miss for all entities with distributionCenterId: '{}'", methodName, distributionCenterId);
            }

            // Fetch the entities from the repository if not found in cache
            response = repo.findAll(distributionCenterId, pageable)
                    .map(entity -> {
                        populateOthers(entity);
                        return createResponse(entity, language);
                    })
                    .map(this::createWrapper);

            // Store the response in the cache if cacheService is available
            if (cacheService != null) {
                List<LR> responseList = response.getContent().stream().map(W::getLogicResponse).collect(Collectors.toList());
                cacheService.storeAll(responseList, distributionCenterId, language.toString(), 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            }

            log.info("{} - Exit. Found all entities: '{}'", methodName, response);

            long endTime = System.nanoTime();
            long duration = endTime - startTime;
            span.tag("duration", String.valueOf(duration));

            return response;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            span.error(e);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            span.end();
        }
    }

I don't know what I am doing wrong but on the initial load I get a request from a different method that tracks some execution time but no detail is given on what exactly it tracked
